# About primitive groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I'm trying to prove that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n$ and $S_n$ are primitive permutation groups on $\Omega=\lbrace{1,2,\cdots,n\rbrace}$.

---

Concepts I am using:

$\bullet$Primitive group$\equiv$ It has no non-trivial blocks.

$\bullet$ In a group $G$, we say $B$ is a block if for every $x\in G$  it verifies either $B\cdot x=B$ or $B\cdot x\cap B=\emptyset$

$\bullet$ We consider that a block is trivial if it is the whole $\Omega$, or a unitary subset of $\Omega$.

---

I think i would have it if I proved that for any subset $\Omega_0\subseteq\Omega$ with $1<|\Omega_0|<|\Omega|$, there exists an element $g\in A_n$ such that $\Omega_0\cdot g\neq \Omega_0$ and $(\Omega_0\cdot g )\cap\Omega_0\neq\emptyset$ (this way, $\Omega_0$ could not be a block).

Any ideas about how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S_n$ contains all permutations on $\Omega$, which includes all $2$-cycles.  Thus, given any subset $\sigma\subset\Omega$, if $1<|\sigma|<|\Omega|$, we can always find one element in $n\in\Omega\backslash\sigma$ and an element $s\in\sigma$. Note $(sn)$ creates a permutation where $\sigma\cdot(sn)\neq \sigma$, since it takes an element out of $\sigma$.  Additionally, $\sigma\cdot(sn)\cap\sigma\neq\emptyset$ since there is more than one element of $\sigma$.

$A_n$ requires only a slightly more complicated argument.  Since $|\sigma|\ge2$, let $s_1,s_2\in\sigma$ where $s_1\neq s_2$.  The $3$-cycle $(ns_1s_2)$ is an element of $A_n$, and $\sigma$ is not a block under this permutation.

Comment: Thanks! Just one doubt: As $A_n<S_n$, if we prove $A_n$ is primitive, can we deduce directly $S_n$ is primitive too? (since every permutation of $A_n$ is a permutation of $S_n$)

Comment: Yes, but I figured it would make more sense to do each individually. I could have just given the $3$-cycle in my answer and been done with it.